# C - how to divide floats?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I get input from command line as a int d. Now I am facing this problem:

```
float a,b;
int d;
float piece;    
printf("Please enter the parts to divide the interval: ");
scanf("%d", &d);

a=0;
b=1;

piece=b-a/(float)d;
printf("%f\n",piece);
```

All I want is to printf some float number dependent on &d. e.g. when I write here 5, I would get 0.20000, for 6 - 0,166666 but I am still getting 1.000000 for all numbers, does anyone knows solution?

Comment: Can you show us the line where you declare `piece`?

Comment: now it is corrected, d is integer and declared as it should be

Comment: You mean "dependent on (the value of) `d`", not "dependent on `&d`".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parenthesis:

```
piece=(b-a)/(float)d;
```

Answer (score 6):

Division has precedence over subtraction, so you need to put the subtraction inside parentheses. You don't have to explicitly cast d to float; dividing a float by it will promote it to float.

```
piece = (b - a) / d;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this line:
`piece=b-a/(float)d;`

should be:
`piece=(float)(b-a)/(float)d;`

Just my 2 cents.

**EDIT**

Since `d` is an int, perhaps try this instead:

`piece=(float)((b-a)/d);`

Comment: Why the additional cast? `a` and `b` are already floats, so `(a-b)` is a float expression. In fact, neither cast is necessary as `d` will automatically be promoted in this expression.

Comment: @Fred Larson: I missed that initially and only saw their initializations, so assumed they were INTs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want:

```
piece = (b - a)/d;
```

I.e., the problem isn't division, but order of operations.